# Store day values individually in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have 7 buttons for days of a week, which have tags from 1 to 7. I like to store those values in core data when tapped. Since arrays are not allowed in core data, how do I individually store them in core data?

Initially, I was getting tags from the button like these

```
@IBAction func dayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }

    if(dayTag.contains((sender as AnyObject).tag!)) {
        if let index = dayTag.firstIndex(of: (sender as AnyObject).tag!) {
            dayTag.remove(at: index)
        }
    } else {
        dayTag.append((sender as AnyObject).tag!)
    }
}
```

and storing them to core data as follows

```
  object.setValue(dayTag, forKey: "days")
```

I am not getting any idea of how to create 7 individual variables and store them into core data when the button is tapped. Any, help in the direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What about creating an entity WeekDay, and use a one to many relationship? Else, you could be able to save a JSON String, use bit flags, etc.

Comment: So, if I create an entity WeekDay, how do I save the values of those buttons in that entity?

Comment: Unrelated but `sender as AnyObject).tag` is horrible. Set the sender of `dayButtonPressed` to `UIButton` and use `sender.tag`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable solution is a computed property.

Declare days as

```
@NSManaged var days: String
```

and declare a computed property

```
var weekdays : [Int] {
    get { return days.components(separatedBy: ",").map{Int($0)!) }
    set { days = newValue.map(String.init).joined(separator: "," }
}
```

Setting `weekdays` converts the `Int` array to a comma separated string and updates `days` (and vice versa).

Comment: I think, I understood the setter, how do I populate the getter with days. components by using the button tags?

Comment: Just ignore `days`. Work with the `Int` array. Any access converts the value accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is such a smart way instead of creating 7 different bools.